# GStreamer Appsrc: how do I get the negotiated caps?

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I am currently using an `appsrc` element in a program I am writing.
I let the user provide a launch string such as this example:

```
appsrc name=mysource format=3 is-live=1 \
  ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=5400, height=3400, framerate=30/1, format=NV12 \
  ! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 control-rate=0 iframeinterval=2 \
  ! h265parse \
  ! matroskamux \
  ! filesink location=myfile.mkv
```

The launch string could be anything, provided it has an `appsrc` called `mysource`.

In my program, I locate `mysource` and I would like to know the `format` property that was provided by the user (to create the right kind of data buffer). I query the `src` pad of my `appsrc` element:

```
    GstPad * pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(m_appsrc, "src");
    if (!pad) fprintf(stderr, "pad is null\n");

    GstCaps * caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
    if (!caps) fprintf(stderr, "caps is null\n");

    for (guint i = 0; i < gst_caps_get_size (caps); i++) {
        GstStructure *structure = gst_caps_get_structure (caps, i);
        g_print ("%s%s\n", "   ", gst_structure_get_name (structure));
        gst_structure_foreach (structure, print_field, (gpointer) "   ");
    }
```

`pad` is non-null, but `caps` is always returned as NULL.

Looking at the .dot graph created by GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT, I'm seeing that the caps indicated on the output of the appsrc are "ANY".

[image: "ANY" caps on output of appsrc "src" pad]

Do I have to do something special like traversing the pipeline to get the final negotiated caps?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if I specify a `caps` property in the `appsrc` launch string, `caps` is not NULL and can be traversed to describe the user-specified capabilities. This is good enough for me:

```
appsrc name=mysource format=3 is-live=1 caps="video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=5400, height=3400, framerate=30/1, format=NV12" \
  ! nvv4l2h265enc bitrate=8000000 control-rate=0 iframeinterval=2 \
  ! h265parse \
  ! matroskamux \
  ! filesink location=myfile.mkv
```